# 12V DC To Household power

Tags: dc, 12v

I have a 12V DC mini air compressor that has a cigarette lighter fitting, now I want to use it for an airbrush kit, can I someway attach a wall plug and use it that way, please excuse my ignorance of this matter it's way out of my field, thankyou.

Comment: Yes there are high current 120V to 12V power supplies with cigarette lighter connectors. Or you can mod a power supply. But a 12v likely car tire compressor may not be the best for an airbrush.

Comment: Agreed @Passerby, go get a small air compressor from a nearby home-improvement store. These of course plug directly into the wall and have a tank (and likely a pressure regulator), both of which the airbrush will need anyways.

Comment: do not use a cheap compressor for an air brush ... you'll get your air brush fouled with oil

Answer (score 1):

You will need a 12 volt DC power supply that can supply the current that the air compressor requires.  Is there a label on the compressor specifying the current (amps) or power (watts) that it requires?

Answer (score 0):

There are adaptors that go from wall power to cigarette outlet. This type of socket typically is rated for 10-15A. So your compressor has to be below that.

Here's a 120V to 12V, 15A 'cigarette socket' adaptor: [https://www.amazon.com/Anfukone-Adapter-Converter-Cigarette-Appliance/dp/B01ET14J8O](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01ET14J8O)

That said, 12V inflator type compressors don't have an air tank so their air delivery is pulsed, and it isn't regulated at all - maybe not what you want for an airbrush. On the other hand, wall-powered air compressors are inexpensive, and the air tank provides some smoothing and so will regulate better.